# Call postgresql stored procedure with composite type array with uuid as one of the input parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have the below user defined composite Type

```
CREATE TYPE item AS (
    SKU_REFERENCE_ID uuid, 
    QUANTITY INTEGER
);
```

And I used it as part of the input parameters of a postgresql stored procedure (showing only relevant part of stored proc)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "dbo"."sp_bulk_update_customer_cart" (IN USER_NAME VARCHAR(20), IN CUSTOMER_ITEMS item[], INOUT QUANTITY INTEGER)
```

However, I am unable to call the procedure.
Here are some things I tried which all failed:

Attempt 1:

```
CALL dbo.sp_bulk_update_customer_cart(
    'username',
    (ARRAY['(e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812, 20)','(ccbecc39-11bd-4bc4-97d6-7e2f981d30dd, 40)'])::item[], 
    0
);
```

Attempt 2:

```
CALL dbo.sp_bulk_update_customer_cart(
    'username',
    '{"(e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812, 20)","(ccbecc39-11bd-4bc4-97d6-7e2f981d30dd, 40)"}'::item[], 
    0
);
```

Attempt 3:

```
CALL dbo.sp_bulk_update_customer_cart(
    'username',
    (SELECT ARRAY[ROW('e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812', 20),ROW('ccbecc39-11bd-4bc4-97d6-7e2f981d30dd', 40)]::item[]), 
    0
);
```

Most common error I get is

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid:
> "(e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812,20)" CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL
> function dbo.sp_bulk_update_customer_cart(character
> varying,item[],integer) line 17 at FOR over SELECT rows SQL state:
> 22P02

Looking for assistance here.

> Using AWS RDS postgres engine version: 13.3

test script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS "dbo"."sp_test_script";

--Not really required as temp tables are deleted after the session ends.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item_table;

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS item;

CREATE TYPE item AS (SKU_REFERENCE_ID uuid, QUANTITY integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "dbo"."sp_test_script" (IN USER_NAME VARCHAR(20), IN CUSTOMER_ITEMS item[], INOUT QUANTITY INTEGER) 

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
    
AS $$

BEGIN

    CREATE TEMP TABLE item_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    SKU_REFERENCE_ID uuid, 
    QUANTITY integer
    );
    
    DECLARE b item;

    BEGIN
        FOR b IN SELECT UNNEST(customer_items)
            LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'b.sku_reference_id: %', b.sku_reference_id; 
                RAISE NOTICE 'b.quantity: %', b.quantity;
                INSERT INTO item_table(SKU_REFERENCE_ID, QUANTITY) VALUES(b.sku_reference_id, b.quantity);
            END LOOP;
    END;

END; $$;
```

Comment: I am able to get the input parameters right using table [] instead of using an array of a composite type as per https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131505/use-array-of-composite-type-as-function-parameter-and-access-it. However, it would be helpful to find the correct input parameters when using type as per my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script problem in iteration over an array - there is an bug in `FOR b IN SELECT UNNEST(customer_items)`. This syntax doesn't do record's unpacking, but `FOR IN SELECT` statement requires it. You need to write:

```
FOR b IN SELECT * FROM unnest(customer_items)
LOOP
  ...
```

or (better)

```
FOREACH b IN ARRAY customer_items
LOOP
  ...
```

Comment: I tried a similar syntax but always get something like this: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: "(e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812,10)"

Comment: both columns (sky_reference_id and quantity are read together. To debug what was sent, please see: NOTICE:  b.sku_reference_id: (e3903331-ce0b-4bd5-a853-ec7aa725a812,10)
NOTICE:  b.quantity: <NULL>

Comment: @CODI - please, attach script, that I can test.

Comment: Don't think it is recommended to attach script so I have updated my question with a test script.

Comment: @CODI - now I am in office, and I changed my reply, and I fixed your issue